# Paso de copia de referencia a objetos en java

Tags: java

Como sabemos java no tiene paso por referencia,solo paso por valor.Para primitivos se pasa la copia en bits equivalentes al valor y para objetos una copia en bits de la referencia de objeto,por lo que en el método se estaria usando una copia de una referencia.Teniendo en cuenta esta introducción me gustaria saber la explicación de por qué el código actúa de la siguiente forma:

```
public   class Main  {

String a ;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m =new Main();
    m.a="a";
anotherMethod(m);
System.out.println(m.a);
someMethod(m);
System.out.println(m.a);}

public static void someMethod(Main m) {
    m.a="someMethod";
    System.out.println(m.a);}
public static void anotherMethod(Main m) {
    m=new Main();
    
    m.a="anotherMethod";
    System.out.println(m.a);}       
}
```

Primero imprime `anotherMethod` seguido de `a`.Luego imprime `someMethod`.Entonces la pregunta sería por qué cuando se llama al método `anotherMethod` se imprime el valor indicado dentro de este pero cuando termina la ejecución del método,la referencia original que se le pasó sigue teniendo el mismo valor?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi respuesta a esto es que en este bloque de codigo:

```
Main m =new Main();
    m.a="a";
anotherMethod(m);
System.out.println(m.a);
```

al método "anotherMethod" se le estaria pasando un valor en bits de la referencia `m` que contiene un objeto,por lo que al entrar en ejecución el metodo,se estaría manipulando una copia de esta,por lo que sus cambios no se verían reflejados en la referencia original ni en el objeto ya que esta copia de la referencia está apuntando a un nuevo objeto.Teniendo en cuenta que todas las variables tienen un ciclo de vida y la que se encuentra dentro de "anotherMethod" es local,los cambios solo perdurarán dentro de este método hasta que se termine su ejecución.Por lo que al llegar al `System.out.println(m.a);`,se estaría utilizando la referencia original que sigue intacta apuntando a su objeto original.

Yendonos por las ramas,para que el cambio dentro de `anotherMethod` surgiera efecto y se viera reflejado en la referencia orignial,lo que debería haber sucedido es que en:
`public static void anotherMethod(Main m) {
m=new Main();

```
m.a="anotherMethod";
System.out.println(m.a);}
```

No se debería de haber cambiado la referencia del argumento m,para que así el cambio de valor en su variable tenga efecto en la referenia original,porque estarían apuntando a una misma direccion de memoria a pesar de ser una copia de una referencia.

Este fue un analisis a partir de un problema que me surgio y que,partiendome un poco la cabeza ,pude encontrarle una explicación.El objetivo de esta publicaión es que a traves de la teoría y el razonamiento que aplique,si en algún momento surgen dudas de como funcionan los pasos de valores en argumentos,puedan utilizar esta explicación teórica que comparti para despejar de dudas.

Comment: Si bien java pasa los objetos como valor, en realidad el valor que pasa es la dirección de memoria de dicho objeto... con lo cual si lo modificas, estarás modificando el original, dado que estás accediendo al mismo objeto (a través de una copia de su dirección de memoria). De esa manera, si pasas un objeto *mutable* a un método, lo que estás haciendo es modificar el original. En cambio, si pasas un objeto *inmutable* (un String por ejemplo), no estarás modificando el original, puesto que java necesita crear una versión nueva de dicho objeto para "modificarlo".